# Select row after a certain ID

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
|   product_id   |       product_date_added     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|       2380     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2379     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2376     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2378     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2375     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2370     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2371     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2381     |      2012-07-03 00:00:00     |
|       ...      |              ...             |
+----------------+------------------------------+
```

What I need to do is to retrieve 5 rows where `$date <= '2012-07-19 00:00:00'`. Then I want to upload my list with the next 5 rows where `$date <= '$Last_Retrieved_Product_Date'` where `$Last_Retrieved_Product_Date` is the `product_date_added` of the last product I retrieved.

The problem is, since they all have the same date (unfortunately they all have no hours-minutes-seconds) this query will retrieve every time the same 5 rows.

What I tried is `$date < '2012-07-19 00:00:00'`, but this will skip, looking at my table, the ids `2370` and `2371` going straight to `2381`.

I also tried to select rows where `$date <= '$Last_Retrieved_Product_Date' AND product_id != 'Last_Product_ID'` but this will make me retrieve the first time `2380, 2379, 2376, 2378, 2375`, the second time `2379, 2376, 2378, 2375 2370`, so I'll have still duplicates.

Is there an `SQL` statement that will make me retrieve all the products_id after a certain value?

For example I could order the table by date and then select 5 rows after the `$Last_Retrieved_Product_ID`.

Please note that the IDs are not ordered, meaning that the latest `product_date_added` doesn't correspond to the highest `product_id`.

**Edit**

What I wold like to have as output.

**First query** 
`SELECT * FROM table Where product_date_added <= '2012-07-19 00:00:00'`
Output:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
|   product_id   |       product_date_added     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|       2380     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2379     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2376     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2378     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2375     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
+----------------+------------------------------+
```

**Second query**
`SELECT * FROM table Where product_date_added <= 'Last_Retrieved_Product_Date'`.

Where `Last_Retrieved_Product_Date` is the `product_date_added` of the row with `product_id = '2375'`

Output desired:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
|   product_id   |       product_date_added     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|       2370     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2371     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2381     |      2012-07-03 00:00:00     |
|       ...      |              ...             |
+----------------+------------------------------+
```

Real Output:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+
|   product_id   |       product_date_added     |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|       2380     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2379     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2376     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2378     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
|       2375     |      2012-07-19 00:00:00     |
+----------------+------------------------------+
```

I'm using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: You mention 2373 but you didn't show it in your data :) To be honest, my eyes glazed over trying to fathom what you need. Perhaps show us the desired output? And let us know what flavour of SQL, too.

Comment: There is a way to do top n queries in most databases but before you write the query, you have to know upon what the top n is based.  You don't appear to have that figured out yet.  Perhaps you should ask the guy who gave you the vague specification.

Comment: @MrFuzzyButton you're right, I meant `2381`, I edited my question to show what I expect and what I get.

@DanBracuk I thought about using `TOP` (in my case, phpmyadmin, I think it's `LIMIT`) but how am I gonna select the `TOP 5` rows after a `product_id` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that with `LIMIT` both upper and lower limit can be set. So I just need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where product_date_added <= '2012-07-19 00:00:00' LIMIT 0, 5
```

And into the second query:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where product_date_added <= '2012-07-19 00:00:00' LIMIT 5, 10
```

Thanks to [Dan Bracuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832636/dan-bracuk) for the suggestion.

Comment: Can I get data after row 5 till the end of the table?